# How to find first occurrence of a character (a-z or A-Z) in a PHP string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to get first occurrence of a character in a string, the character can be any from (a-z or A-Z).

I am able to get the first occurrence of an integer from the string by using the following function:

```
function my_ofset($text){
    preg_match('/^\D*(?=\d)/', $text, $m);
    return isset($m[0]) ? strlen($m[0]) : false;
}
```

It returns the position of first occurrence of an integer from the string, but unable to do this in case of characters.

Comment: Have you looked into `str_pos()`

Comment: @stribizhev, have edited my question, please review

Comment: If you write *a-z or A-Z*, try `preg_match('/^[^a-z]*(?=[a-z])/i', $text, $m);`

Comment: @stribizhev, wow! perfect, thanks so much for such a quick response :)

Comment: I added some explanations in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your regex to meet the current requirement to find the position of the first Latin letterm you can use

```
preg_match('/^[^a-z]*(?=[a-z])/i', $text, $m);
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^a-z]*` - 0 or more characters other than a Latin letter up to...
- `(?=[a-z])` - a Latin letter (though this letter is not consumed, is not part of the match).

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FwrkZk)

Note that `/i` modifier allows case-insensitive search (thus, no need using `[a-zA-Z]`).

As an alternative, you may use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`:

> **`PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`**
>   If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of matches into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset `0` and its string offset into subject at offset `1`.

Here is a demo:

```
preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $text, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $m[0][1];
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XmBszE)

Here, `$m[0]` is the whole matched text, and `$m[0][1]` is the offset (=index) of the matched substring inside the input.

Comment: I am not touching the Unicode aspect here since your requirement looks to be only the ASCII Latin letters. If it is all letters you need, the solution will be a bit different: `'/^\P{L}*(\p{L})/u'`. And if you need to calculate the length, you'd need `mb_strlen`.

Comment: @stribizhev: Why not just `\p{L}` or `[a-z]`? Effectively, the first character is captured.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function my_ofset($text){
    preg_match('/^[^a-z]*(?=[a-z])/i', $text, $m);
    return isset($m[0]) ? strlen($m[0]) : false;
}
```